# Same code, one works one doesn't. What's different?

Tags: c++, function, object, error-handling

i'm an beginner programmer, this is my first time posting. I'm currently writing a snake game in c++. Most of the game wasn't so hard to implement but when it came to the tail of the snake the entire program broke. I spent like 2 hours trying to figure out what was wrong and then i decided to try to rewrite the problematic code.
From my understanding i haven't changed a thing but now it works. Can someone explain to me what changed?
Here is the code, the commented one is not working the other works fine:

```
   else { 
            bool eCoada = false;
            for (int s = 0; s <= ntail; s++)
            {
                if (tail[s].height == j && tail[s].width == k)
                { eCoada = true; break; }

            }
            if (eCoada == false)  cout << " ";
            else cout << "o";
        }
    /*  else  {
            bool eCoada = false;
        for (int s = 0;s <= ntail; s++)
        {
            if (tail[s].height==j &&  k==tail[s].width==k)
            { eCoada = true; break; }
            if (eCoada==false)  cout << " ";
            else cout << "o";
        }
               
            }*/
```

Also i should mention that this code is a part of a function, if you want me to post the full code i will do so.

Comment: What was your intention with `k==tail[s].width==k`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`k==tail[s].width==k` is not the same as `tail[s].width == k`. You may think you've written something like `(k == tail[s].width) && (tails[s].width == k`. But C++ doesn't automatically put in `&&` operators like that. What actually happens is that the [associativity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) of the `==` operator is left to right. So what that actually means is

`(k == tails[s].width) == k`

Assuming `k` and `tails[s].width` are `int`s, that means `(k == tails[s].width)` is a `bool`. The comparison between that and `k` will be checking if `k` is `0` or `1`, instead of checking if it matches the width as intended.

---

Another difference is in the placement if your `if(eCoada==false)` line.

In your working code, it's *after* the `for` loop finishes, which means that it only executes once.

In your broken code, it's *inside* the `for` loop, which means that every time the loop executes it prints a space. It also means that because you `break` out of the loop immediately upon setting `eCoada` to `true`, you never execute the `else` branch and never print an `o`.

Comment: I edited the answer to address another difference between the two versions of your code.

Answer (score 0):

C++, nor any other language that I know of, doesn't allow multiple comparisons in one statement.
You can't say is x == y == z,
you must break them up.
if(x ==y && y == z)

Comment: Minor point: you can, in fact, say `x == y == z`, but the resulting value isn't particularly useful.